# No time and date on lock screen

Tags: insider-preview, lock-screen

I have installed Windows 10 preview, but after installing date and time is not showing on lock screen.

Comment: Can you unlock the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a hard reset - this usually fixes most issues with the preview (unless those are specifically mentioned by Microsoft).